# Gap between toolbar & picker in?

Tags: ios, swift, toolbar, ios11, iqkeyboardmanager

I am facing a strange issue.I have created the UIPicker with below code.I have also used IQKeyboardManager for managing the Keyboard.

```
let datepicker = UIPickerView()

        datepicker.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: -10, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 200)
        datepicker.backgroundColor = Constants.Colors.blue
        datepicker.tintColor = UIColor.white
        textfieldDropDown.inputView = datepicker
        textfieldDropDown.inputView?.autoresizingMask = .flexibleHeight
        datepicker.delegate = self
        datepicker.reloadAllComponents()
```

[image]

**Temporary solution**
If i set the height to 220 then it does not show any gap because of more height.

Please tell me the best solution for this ?

Answer (score 5):

datePicker.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

Comment: Thanks but this did not work for me so what i did is to increase height

Comment: This one helped me

Answer (score 1):

There's an update in iOS 11 to picker, in order to fix it first of all change your

```
[[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 100, self.view.frame.size.width, 200)]
```

to

```
[UIPickerView new]
```

also change

```
[[UIToolbar alloc] init]
```

to

```
[UIToolbar new]
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't set any frame for `UIPickerView` just declare it as

```
let datepicker = UIPickerView()
```

Same for `UIToolbar` like,

```
let toolBar = UIToolbar()
```

That's It !